# converting numpy datetime64 in a numba jitclass to unix timestamp

Tags: python, numba

For the sake of readability I want to be able to supply a numpy.datetime64 object to a numba jitclass which is converted to a unix epoch timestamp in float format within the class itself.

I currently have to resort to calculating the unix timestamp prior to creating the jitclass object and supply this as a parameter, e.g.:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> (np.datetime64('2024-01-01T00:00:00') - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) / np.timedelta64(1, 's')
1704067200.0
```

Suppose that I create the following jitclass that takes a numpy datetime as parameter, how can I create a method within the class that converts the datetime into a unix timestamp? The ultimate goal would be to supply a start and end date when creating the jitclass object, which are then converted to unix timestamps in order to create an array of timestamps using `np.arange()`.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from numba import types

spec=[
    ('start', types.NPDatetime('s'))
]

@jitclass(spec)
class Foo():

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

obj = Foo(np.datetime64('2024-01-01T00:00:00'))
```

```
>>> obj.start
numpy.datetime64('2024-01-01T00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to create something like `to_timestamp()` method in the `Foo` class:

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

spec = [("start", nb.types.NPDatetime("s"))]

_unix_timestamp_begin = np.datetime64("1970-01-01T00:00:00")
_one_second = np.timedelta64(1, "s")


@nb.experimental.jitclass(spec)
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start

    def to_timestamp(self):
        return (self.start - _unix_timestamp_begin) / _one_second


obj = Foo(np.datetime64("2024-01-01T00:00:00"))
print(obj.to_timestamp())
```

Prints:

```
1704067200.0
```

Comment: That indeed seems to do the trick. I was under the impression that jitclasses couldn't handle global variables but this seems to work.